# How to Instruct JVM to keep memory footprint as low as possible?

Tags: java, jvm

I have a java program that performs 5 different tasks. When I run the program with -Xmx512m memory parameter, tasks 1-4 run fine but task 5 goes out of memory. When I run the program with -Xmx1024m, all 5 tasks runs fine but tasks 1-4 that previously ran fine with 512m heap now uses up almost all of 1024m heap. The same thing happens if I use -Xms128m -Xmx1024m.

What would be the memory parameters to instruct JVM to keep the memory utilization low (e.g. 512m for tasks 1-4) and only to use more memory when actually needed (e.g. in case of task 5)?

Maybe I need a way to activate the garbage collector more frequently than the default setting?

Comment: How are you differentiating which tasks use what amount of memory?

Comment: Why does it matter how much tasks 1-4 use? You've already allocated a gigabyte for the whole program anyway.

Comment: @Poindexter  I pass a command line parameter to indicate which task to run. Then I use `prstat` to view the memory utilization of the program.

Comment: @Michael Myers I don't intend the program to use all 1g heap always. My intention is to instruct the JVM to use 512m heap if it can manage and to use more memory only if required. And when the extra memory is no more required, fall back to 512m or even less.

Comment: The JVM reserves the maximum heap size on startup and never gives it back to the OS (unless it exits). Unless you have a very limited machine, I wouldn't worry about it, 512 MB of memory is worth about $3.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you have a misunderstanding on how the JVM works. This is not a GC issue or a "task" issue.

Your tasks have memory leaks or they are designed to hold onto more and more memory.

-Xmx1024m sets the maximum memory the JVM can allocate. It'd be the same thing as if you only have 1024 megs of physical memory and no virtual memory.

It would be helpful to update your question with the definition of Task. Are these 5 separate JVM's? Or just 5 units of work in a single JVM.

**Update**

> I don't intend the program to use all 1g heap always. My intention is to instruct the JVM to use 512m heap if can manage and to use more memory only if required. When the memory is no more required, to fall back to 512m or even less amount of memory.

Just because you set -Xmx1024m does not mean the JVM WILL use all that memory. It's just a max limit. Setting Xms till set a minimum amount of memory to be used. Your program ultimately determines the running amount of memory being utilized. If it hits the limit set by -Xmx then it will throw an OutOfMemoryError

You can suggest to the JVM to run the Garbage Collector by invoking `System.gc()`. Notice I said suggest, you cannot force the GC to run. You could be running on a platform that refuses to even do GC. You also need to look into what GC algorithm it is choosing for your application. I would look here [Tuning Garbage Collector](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/gc-tuning-5-138395.html).

If you need such fine grain controls over memory usage you will need to pick something else besides the JVM.

Comment: When I run the program, I pass a command line parameter indicating which of the 5 tasks the program is to execute. During the lifetime of the program, while running the requested task, I monitor the memory utilization of the program. In case of task 1-4, when I use -Xmx512m, I observe the memory utilization rises to roughly 512m before completion. When I use -Xmx1024m, the memory utilization rises to roughly 1024m before completion when it could have used only 512m.

Comment: @Raihan There are two things I can think of for this. You are looking at non swapped memory. Or the GC is not running as aggressively when you give it more memory so it is valuing performance over memory usage. If it realizes it is about to run out of memory it will try to free as many dangling references. If it has plenty of memory it can leave them alone for a bit.

Comment: @Raihan If you have to stick with the JVM, find the max amount of memory you should need to run in all cases. Then suggest for the system to GC with System.gc(). In your -Xmx1024m case, invoke System.gc() and then see if your usage is higher. Also keep in mind to read the correct memory values. Just because the JVM deallocated all the memory doesn't mean the OS is willing to take all the memory away from the process just yet.

Answer (score 10):

These two parameters suggest the jvm when it needs to adjust its heap size:

```
-XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio=10
-XX:MinHeapFreeRatio=10
```

which pretty much means that if after gc, more than 10% of the heap is free, it will try to give the memory back to the OS. and it will grow the heap only if more than 90% of the heap is used after gc.

this might slow down your program, because the gc will be constantly changing allocated memory size. and it is possible that it will have no effect at all if your program allocates large amount of memory in a short period of time.

Answer (score 1):

By passing -Xmx1024m to th VM you basically tell the VM that it can use up to 1 gig of heap, which it will eventually do. The VM starts to run garbage collection when it is needed, eg. when heap becomes used up, which depends on the available heap size.
If you know which task to run outside (which I guess you do because you pass it as cmd line parameter), why not set the -Xmx from outside too?

Comment: Is there a way to suggest the garbage collector not to wait until all -Xmx amount of heap is used up before starting, instead to start whenever some `X` amount new memory is allocated?

Comment: There is a whole bunch of flags you can play around with: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html I am not too sure about the impact some of those flags have though.

Answer (score 1):

try to use http://visualvm.java.net/ in order to see memory consumption. Then you may use jhat to visualize heap content and http://www.eclipse.org/mat/ to identify leaks.